# Automate process that needs user interaction not working in ubuntu using expect package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, background, expect

I want to automate the running of a process in Ubuntu using Expect.

The process that I have asks the user to insert "ok" and then ask them to insert a password.

I've created an Expect script to automate the operation

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -ignore HUP /home/startclef.cmd

expect "ok"

send "ok\r"

sleep 5

expect "Please enter the password to decrypt the master seed"

sleep 5

send "pass_123\r"

sleep 5

interact

expect_background
```

I stored the previous script in a file named script.expect

When I execute the script in this way

```
./script.expect
```

it's working perfectly, but I want to run the process in the background so I executed the script in this way:

```
./script.expect &
```

it returns an error

```
liner: function not supported in this terminal
```

Comment: try replacing `interact; expect_background` with just `expect -timeout -1 eof`.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells Same issue